# Modify the style for a specific node selected in the network for vis.js

Tags: javascript, vis.js

Is there a way to change the node size for the selected node without changing the size for all nodes in the options ?

These are my node options:

```
nodes: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderWidthSelected: 2,
    physics: true,
    color: {
        border: '#000000',
        background: '#ffffff',
        highlight: {
            border: '#000000',
            background: '#B9B9BF'
        }
    },
    shadow: {
        enabled: false,
        color: '#C11818',
        size: 10,
        x: 5,
        y: 5
    },
    shape: 'circularImage',
    mass: 2,
    size: 25
}
```

I want to enlarge the selected node so it is more visible than the others.

```
network.on("selectNode", function (params) {
    var nodeId = params.nodes[0];
    var node = nodes.get(nodeId);
    nodeClick(nodeId, nodes, edges, network);
    // var options= {
    // nodes: {
    // size: 40
    // }
    // };
    // network.setOptions(options);
});
```

The commented part sets the size for all nodes rather than the one selected and the node object doesn't have any handle on the options either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have multiselect enabled, you can loop over params.nodes

```
for (id in params.nodes){
    var node = network.body.nodes[params.nodes[id]];
    ...
}
```

(deselect respectivly)

Answer (score 6):

You can change the font-size of the selected node to increase its size:

```js
var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
  {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
  {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
  {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
  {id: 5, label: 'Node 5'}
]);
var edges = new vis.DataSet([
  {from: 1, to: 2},
  {from: 2, to: 4},
  {from: 2, to: 5}
]);

var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
var data = { 
  nodes: nodes,
  edges: edges
};
var options = {
  interaction: { hover:true },
  nodes: { font: { size: 14 }}
};
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);

network.on("selectNode", function (params) {
  var selectedNodeId = params.nodes[0];
  var node = network.body.nodes[selectedNodeId];
  node.setOptions({
    font: {
      size: 20
    }
  });
});

network.on("deselectNode", function (params) {
  var deselectedNodeId = params.previousSelection.nodes[0];
  var node = network.body.nodes[deselectedNodeId];
  node.setOptions({
    font: {
      size: options.nodes.font.size
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#mynetwork {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.16.1/vis.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.16.1/vis.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mynetwork"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This definitely helps. But I just want to be sure that there is no other way to increase the diameter of the node before I accept the answer. I use a circular image for nodes and the label is displayed under each node.
BTW, I did not know you could set node options that way. I use a Dataset for nodes. `nodes = new vis.DataSet()` The setOptions was not available there. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using  `font: {size:20}` I could just use `size:25` and that will enlarge the node. Thanks for your answer.